# Updating SwiftUI View from background

Tags: swiftui, watchos

When my watchOS app starts, `AppDelegate`'s applicationDidFinishLaunching kicks off a background thread which does some things and updates the `View`.

In SwiftUI, the `View` cannot be updated just like that. All `View`s are functions of state. Altering the state would 'refresh' the `View`.

With the above concept in mind, there's the following `MessageView`:

```
public struct MessageView: View {
    
    init(_ message: String) {
        
        self.message = message
    }
    
    @State
    public var message: String 
    
    public var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "globe")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .foregroundStyle(.tint)
            Text(message)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

This `MessageView` is initialised with sample data in a `StaticContext`... even before the `AppDelegate` is invoked.

```
public struct StaticContext {
    
    public static var messageView: MessageView = MessageView("[Lifecycle]: Hellow World!")
}

// App Struct
@main
struct WatchOSStartup_Watch_AppApp: App {
    
    @WKApplicationDelegateAdaptor
    var appDelegate: AppDelegate
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            StaticContext.messageView
        }
    }
}
```

With the above style, I'm able to store a reference to the `MessageView` before giving it to SwiftUI. When my background thread is done with its work (most of it is in C++), it can use this reference to alter the state of `MessageView` and therefore update `MessageView`.

```
@objc
static func updateUIMessage() {
      
    StaticContext.messageView.message = "[Presentation]: Hello World!"
}
```

When state is altered, the `View` must refresh and the new data is supposed to get displayed? But I only see the previous message. Not sure why... Is this approach even okay? If not, how to update a SwiftUI `View` from background thread?

PS:
This is only a basic model. Eventually, I'm expecting to have bunch of properties which can affect a `View`. So, I should be using `@StateObject`, `@ObservedObject` and have a custom type (conforming to the `ObservableObject` protocol) as the state of the `View`. I wanted to test a very basic model first.

Comment: State can’t be updated like that. In fact, State should always be private, which would prevent that mistake. Shared state needs to be held at the highest parent level. Check out the Apple or Hacking with Swift SwiftUI tutorials to understand how data management in the framework works.

Comment: `.task` or `.onAppear` are better places for this. Also although you said watchOS but if on iPad or Mac if another window appears you can check if you have already done the app launch only work before starting it again.

Comment: Go through the Apple SwiftUI Tutorials. static in a View isn’t capable of triggering a redraw. Also don’t hold mutable Views in variables, it will never work as you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some reading and this helpful WWDC video about [Data Essentials in SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc20/10040), I'm able to update a `View` from a background thread.

This is my sample data model:

```
public class MessageViewData: ObservableObject {

    init(_ message: String) {
        
        self.message = message
    }
    
    @Published
    public var message: String
}
```

This is the `MessageView`:

```
public struct MessageView: View {
    
    public init(messageData: MessageViewData) {
        
        self.messageData = messageData
    }
    
    // Not a Source of Truth.
    @ObservedObject
    var messageData: MessageViewData
    
    public var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "globe")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .foregroundStyle(.tint)
            Text(messageData.message)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

As shown above, the `MessageView` doesn't hold on to the data (aka the 'Source of Truth'), but only a reference to it. The lifecycle of the data is managed externally. In my case, I've created a static object of type `MessageViewData`

```
public class AppDelegate: NSObject, WKApplicationDelegate {
    
    public func applicationDidFinishLaunching() {
        
        // UI related initialization
        // Note: SwiftUI view is not initialzed yet.
        
        // Run a background thread for 10 sec to mock the application logic of
        // 1) Initialize other app components
        // 2) Read from disk
        // And finally, update the UI by updating 'Source of Truth'
        let queue: DispatchQueue = DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background)
        queue.async {
            
            var presentDate: Date = Date.now
            Log("Start time = " + String(describing: presentDate))
            for i in 1...2 {
                
                // Sleep for 5 sec
                Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 5)
                
                // Then count
                presentDate = Date.now
                Log(String(format: "%d) %@", i, String(describing: presentDate)))
            }
            Log("End time = " + String(describing: presentDate))
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
            
                Log("Updating Source of Truth...")
                AppDelegate.messageData.message = "Update"
            }
        }
    }
    
    // Source of Truth of the data passed to SwiftUI. The lifecycle of this data
    // is managed by the AppDelegate and not any SwiftUI View.
    public static var messageData: MessageViewData = MessageViewData("Default")
}
```

The data initialised in AppDelegate is injected into MessageView as shown below:

```
@main
struct WatchOSStartup_Watch_AppApp: App {
    
    @WKApplicationDelegateAdaptor
    var appDelegate: AppDelegate
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            
            // Inject data to SwiftUI view.
            // The Source of Truth is defined as a static member in
            // the AppDelegate.
            MessageView(messageData: (AppDelegate.messageData))
        }
    }
}
```